# "Token has expired or is not yet valid" for token from FirebaseUser.getToken(true)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We experience problems with authentication when on Android:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
Task<GetTokenResult> tokenTask = firebaseUser.getToken(true)
      .addOnCompleteListener(TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD, null);
try {
    token = Tasks.await(tokenTask).getToken();
} catch (Throwable e) { }
```

and on Java server:

```
Task<FirebaseToken> authTask = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(principal.getClientToken());

try {
    Tasks.await(authTask);
} catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException e ) {  }
if (authTask.isSuccessful()) {
    firebaseToken = authTask.getResult();
} else {
    log.error(authTask.getException().getMessage());
}
```

The problem is that we got in log (that corresponds to above logging statement):

```
Token has expired or is not yet valid
```

We also dump device number and resulted token and can use it successfully afterwards with requests on server so Java server validate this token...

What is meaning of `is not yet valid`? Do we need to wait some time before token become valid?

Because of `firebaseUser.getToken(true)` on Android we can't authenticate mobile client.

We change this to `firebaseUser.getToken(false)`. This call return same token between calls for a long period of time and after some delay (near 40 sec) from first attempt token is validated by server. So after several attempts mobile application is able to authenticate.

The time necessary to wait for token to become valid within a minute and this can be issue with time mismatching on Google servers...

On Android  we work with:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
```

on server we work with:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1'
```

Comment: did you try to upgrade your firebase server admin sdk? Version 3.0.1 seems to be deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging issue further we found that local authentication server depends on hardware time.

Our hosting virtual server late on 7 min from current time.

Fixing VM hardware time settings is resolved our problem.

It is not wise for Google to depend on malformed local server time. At least on broken VM time is consistent, they most probably compare time with other parties so we resulted in error.

Comment: It was really useful, i didn't know what verify anymore. It was what you said, my server time was wrong ~5min late. I just updated firewall rules `sudo ufw allow ntp`, and everything was fine. thx